# how to boot a live-system with proprietary ATI drivers / fglrx?

Tags: boot, ati, live-usb, fglrx, proprietary

Is it possible to boot a live system which is using the proprietary ATI drivers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it persistent. Utilities like Startup Disk Creator and Unetbootin allow you to make a persistent USB drive. In such systems, changes you make, such as installing packages, drivers, etc., are preserved across reboots.

In Startup Disk Creator:
[image]

Select some reasonable storage space, like 2GB. Then use it boot in a system with a network connection and install the drivers.

Another option is to customize the live image: [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: The propriety drivers will not work with persistence, you need a custom iso, initrd really.